# Java HttpUrlConnection throws Connection Refused

Tags: java, httpconnection

I know there are several question regarding this topic But I did't find an answer in any of them.

I'm trying to open a connection to my local server but I keep getting connection refused.

I have the server running and I tested the connection with the Browser and with a Google App called Postman and it works.

It's failing when opening the connection as if there where nothing to connect to. or maybe something is blocking the connection? I tested with firewall and antivirus down, no luck.

testing in Postman the URL returns a User as it should...

If I replace the url with "http://www.google.com" It Works fine.

here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 *
 * @author Gabriel
 */
public class HttpConnection {

    public HttpConnection() {

    }

    public void makeRequest() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        String url = "http://localhost:8000/users/1";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6");
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        con.setRequestProperty("Host", "localhost:8000");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());


    }
}
```

Comment: And the browser is on the same computer that you're running Java from?

Comment: yes ... my guess is that something is blocking Java from opening the local connection :P

Comment: Ok, I've tried just connecting to http://localhost and it works,, the problem is http://localhost:8000 :p I dont know why

Comment: for some reason I get connection refused when I try to connect to port 8000

Comment: That means your web server is not running on port 8000. can you access the same url from browser?

Comment: I'll explain further, im using Laravel and I'm running a Development server on port 8000, And Yes,, Am able to access it through the browser

Comment: So to be perfectly clear, you can browse to `"http://localhost:8000/users/1"` with your browser?

Comment: Yes, it returns user 1 as it should

Comment: What's going on is either *really* interesting and you'll have to do some fun debugging to figure it out, of it's facepalm-stupid.

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich I am facing a exact same issue. Were you able to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Can you post the config of the http server you are trying to connect to.

Comment: What happens if you change localhost to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich Any specific error you get like timedOut ..

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich Your code is working smoothly in my computer. Could something be wrong with your server? What kind of server is it? Could you test against vs dummy server? https://github.com/alessiop86/dummy-server

Comment: just use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, it should work

Answer (score 6):

I faced exactly the same problem. Use this instead of localhost:

`http://[::1]:8000/index.php`

Comment: Thank you sir, never thought it would be ipv6...
Sometimes using the IPv6 loopback address can resolve issues with localhost.

Comment: Thank you! I was in this specific situation. http://::1:8000 worked in Postman, but not in my java client. Adding brackets solved the problem!

Answer (score 3):

I have similar code that is working, but my request header is a lot simpler. Basically just:

```
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
```

If simplifying the header does not help, I would capture the traffic when using your browser with something like fiddler and then making the request look exactly like that.

Answer (score 2):

I will make a wild guess what can be the problem. It is possible a IPv4/IPv6 problem.

If so, here is two possible solutions

- If the server is only listening on an ipv6 address, change it to listening to ipv4.
- If the server is listening to ipv4, then force Java to use ipv4 with
  `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. My url is something like "http://my-host-name:51234/abc". It works from browser, but now from java HttpUrlconnection.

Comment: if I change it to "http://locahost:8080/abc" it works from java code. Not sure why using "my-host-name" doesn't work for me.

Comment: Ok, does is work when you have the actual IP instead of the hostname `my-host-name`? If it does then it is a problem translating the hostname to the IP, i.e. a DNS problem.

Comment: Another possibility could be the "Address Cache", if might have cached a failed lookup attempt for `my-host-name`. You can read more about it in the last paragraph here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html

Comment: Thats really weird, and I guess this is not how you really escaped the java string. Could you provide the actual code, this is getting even more interesting!

Comment: I know its totally weird

Comment: Ah, i see. You are giving the hostname from a terminal as an input parameter. Did you try writing the hostname directly in the code?

Comment: Yes I did, same issue :)

Comment: So strange! Just of curiosity, how did you write that one? Can you provide the one that is working and the one is not working? Thanks :)

Comment: "http://t-mb-vik:50925/help?id=12345" doesn't work.. "http://t\-mb\-vik:50925/help?id=12345" works.

Comment: I tried the same on some other mac, and there both those urls work.

Comment: Sorry, my request was a bit unclear. What I wanted was the Java code that worked/not worked with "hardcoded" urls. :)

Comment: This is the client code http://pastie.org/10762977. I have a local server running with /help endpoint. "t-mb-vik:50925/help?id=12345" doesn't work for the above code (throws connnection refused). http://t\-mb\-vik:50925/help?id=12345" works for the above code and returns 200.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
    System.out.println(address.getHostAddress()); .. For host = "localhost" I get 127.0.0.1, but for "t-mb-vik" I get the external ip. I checked my /etc/hosts file and it looks good. In fact I wrote a C program and that returns 127.0.0.1. This boils down to jvm not able to read the updated /etc/hosts file or is caching something.

Comment: Summarized the problem in a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089518/java-local-hostname-ip-resolution

Comment: I believe it could be the problem of local hosts file is not getting access for Java program. Or may be there could be your server application is not running

Answer (score 2):

You can try implementing CORS at the API you are trying to connect by setting `access-control-allow-origin:*` property in response header.

Answer (score 1):

The code is good and works great. Now the problem must be on the transportation or network part. What I want to mean is you don't request the right server. If you use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost I think you won't get a problem. So, my guest will be that you have a problem in `/etc/hosts` or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

I advice you to try a simple test: ping the hostname and check in the output if the ip address is good.

Answer (score 0):

Well, put `http://localhost:8000/users/1` in your web browser and what do you get? A simple `Connection Refused` error. It's not you, it's the website. Also, `Url` returns websites using `Protocol Identifiers(http://, https://)`, `Ending Domains(.com, .edu, .gov)` that's also another reason why you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you were opening a connection to your "local server" 
I am assuming that you are doing this on the same computer that you're hosting the server on?

- Try to open the connection to your local server using a different computer.